# If a normal element of a C* algebra has real spectrum, then it is self-adjoint

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, c-star-algebras

> Let $A$ be a $C^*\!$-algebra. Suppose $x$ is a normal element of $A$ and $\operatorname{spect}(x)$ lies in $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that $x$ is self-adjoint.

I tried the following: using $\operatorname{spect}(x)=\overline{\operatorname{spect}(x^*)}$   conclude that $\lambda -a=\lambda-a^* \implies a=a^*$ for $\lambda$ in $\operatorname{spect}(a)$. Is this valid?

Comment: Any attempts so far?

Comment: I don't understand what it means "spect(x) lies in R.I know that if x is normal --> r(x)=||x||

Comment: I think this is the solution:
spec(x)=spec(x*) (with an over line) therefore ג-a=ג-a* --> a=a*
for ג in spect(a)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There may well be a simpler solution. (But see a certain comment below.)

Since a $C^*$ algebra is semi-simple it's enough to show that $\phi(x^*)=\phi(x)$ for every complex homomorphism $\phi$ of $A$. Since we're given that $\phi(x)$ is real, it's enough to show $$\phi(x^*)=\overline{\phi(x)}.$$I was surprised to find a few years ago when I was working this out that that last bit *cannot* be proved by purely algebraic fiddling; it depends on completeness! There are simple examples of things satisfying all of the definition of "$C^*$ algebra" *except* completeness of the norm, where $\phi(x^*)\ne\overline{\phi(x)}$ in general.

EDIT: The example is described at the bottom of the post, due to popular demand.

Now to show that $\phi(x^*)=\overline{\phi(x)}$ it's enough to show that *if* $y*=y$ then $\phi(y)\in\mathbb R$. Given this, then in general $\phi(x+x^*)$ and $\phi((x-x^*)/i)$ are both real, and it follows that $\phi(x^*)=\overline{\phi(x^*)}$.

So we need this:

Lemma If $x=x^*$ then $\phi(x)\in \mathbb R$.

The standard proof: For $y$ in any Banach algebra with identity define $$\exp(y)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{y^n}{n!},$$where $y^0=\mathbb 1$, the identity. *If* $y_1y_2=y_2y_1$ then it's easy to see that $$\exp(y_1+y_2)=\exp(y_1)\exp(y_2).$$Continuity of the involution and of the complex homomorphism $\phi$ show that $$\exp(x^*)=(\exp(x))^*,\quad\phi(\exp(x))=\exp(\phi(x)).$$

Suppose now that $x^*=x$ and define $z:\mathbb R\to Z$ by $$z(t)=\exp(itx).$$
*Since* $x^*=x$ we have $$z^*z=\exp((itx)^*)\exp(itx)=\exp(it(-x^*+x^*))=\exp(0)=\mathbb 1.$$That is, $z$ is *unitary*. Now $||z|||^2=||z^*z||=1$, so $||z||=||z^*||=1$, so $|\phi(z)|\le1$ and $|\phi(z^*)|\le1$. On the other hand, $\phi(z^*)\phi(z)=1$. So $|\phi(z)|=|\phi(z^*)|=1$.

Hence for every real $t$ we have $$\left|\exp(it\phi(x))\right|=|\phi(z(t))|\le1,$$and hence $\phi(x)\in\mathbb R$.

---

For that example. Let $A$ be the space of trigonometric polynomials $$f(t)=\sum_{n=-N}^Nc_ne^{int},$$with  norm $$||f||=\sup_{t\in\mathbb R}|f(t)|$$and involution $$f^*=\overline f.$$(So the completion of $A$ is just $C(\mathbb T)$ with the usual norm and involution.) Define $$\phi(f)=\sum_{n=-N}^Nc_n2^n.$$It's clear that $\phi(f^*)\ne\overline{\phi(f)}$. If it's not clear that $\phi$ is multiplicative, note that $A$ can be viewed as the space of finite Laurent series (i.e. rational functions with no poles except possibly at $0$ and $\infty$) and if we look at $A$ that way then $\phi(f)=f(2)$. (If we look at $A$ as a set of rational functions then the description of the involution takes more space, hence the official definition as the space of trigonometric polynomials.)

Note that $\phi$ is not continuous; the automatic continuity of complex homomorphisms also depends on completeness.

Comment: I really anjoyed your enswer. thank you for answering my question,now it's clearer!!!

Comment: Your first comment is interesting: Does that mean that the completion of your counterexample is not a $C^{\ast}$-algebra? or that the offending homomorphism cannot be extended to the completion? The latter seems unlikely because of uniform continuity though.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan The offending homomorphism does not extend to the completion.  It's not continuous. Ludiicrously simple example described in an edit to my answer...

Answer (score 3):

Let $B = C^*(x) \subseteq A$ be the $C^*$-subalgebra generated by $x$. Note that $B$ is commutative, since $x$ is normal. Furthermore, recall that $\text{spect}_B(x) \cup \{0\} = \text{spect}_A(x) \cup \{0\}$ holds whenever $B$ is a $C^*$-subalgebra of $A$, so we have $\text{spect}_B(x) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ as well.

The Gelfand representation now gives an isometric $*$-isomorphism $\varphi : B \to C_0(\Omega)$ for some locally compact Hausdorff space $\Omega$. Now let $\hat x = \varphi(x)$ denote the Gelfand transform of $x$. For all $\tau \in \Omega$ we have
$$\hat x(\tau) \in \text{spect}_{C_0(\Omega)}\big(\:\hat x\:\big) = \text{spect}_B(x) \subseteq \mathbb{R}, $$
so we see that $\hat x$ is a real-valued (i.e. self-adjoint) element of $C_0(\Omega)$. As $\varphi$ is a $*$-isomorphism, it follows that $x$ is self-adjoint as well.

---

**Edit:** To answer the question, your proof is incorrect. You can deduce $\text{spect}(x) = \overline{\text{spect}(x)} = \text{spect}(x^*)$, but different elements of $A$ can have the same spectrum, even if both of them are normal. For instance, let $p$ and $q$ be projections such that $|\{0,\mathbb{1},p,q\}| = 4$ holds (that is, they are all different), then we have $\text{spect}(p) = \text{spect}(q) = \{0,1\}$ by [the argument given here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/890951/246783), but we have $p\neq q$.