# Non-commutative spectrum in Banach Algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, operator-theory, spectral-theory, banach-algebras

I am currently starting to learn about Banach Algebras/Spectral theory. And I have the following question: Take $\mathcal{A}:=B(l^2(\mathbb N))$ as a Banach Algebra. And consider the right shift operator
$$
T( (x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}) = 
\begin{cases}
0 ,\quad & n = 1 \\
x_{n-1} , \quad & n > 1
\end{cases}
$$
We need to prove that $\sigma(T^{\ast} T) \neq \sigma(T T^{\ast})$, where $\sigma$ denotes the spectrum. (Usually this is defined only for elements in the Banach Algebra but by abuse of notation, we need to find an element in the algebra, such that the spectra differ from one-another).

My progress: Clearly $T^{\ast} : l^2(\mathbb N) \to l^2(\mathbb N)$ is the left shift-operator. Thus consider $x \in \mathcal{A}$, then
$$
T^{\ast} T x = (x_1,x_2,\dots) \quad T T^{\ast} x = (0,x_2,x_3,\dots)
$$
This reflects that we have a Hilbert-Space structure i.e. the adjoint is the inverse operator. So for $x=0 \in \mathcal A$, I believe that $0 \notin \sigma(T^{\ast} T)$ but $0 \in \sigma(T T^{\ast})=B_1(0)$. However I am not 100% sure that one can deduct the last equality from knowing the spectrum of the right shift? Moreover, can we deduce more information about the Banach Algebra if we know that $\sigma(T^{\ast} T) \neq \sigma(T T^{\ast})$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have that $T^*T=I$, the identity operator, and it is trivial to check that $\sigma(I)=\{1\}$. Meanwhile, $TT^*=I-P$, where $P$ is the projection onto the first coordinate. Then $\sigma(TT^*)=\{0,1\}$, as such is [the spectrum of any nontrivial idempotent](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/891270/22857).

Comment: Concerning the details, for $\sigma(I) = \{1\}$ is clear. However for $TT^{\ast}T = I-P$ I have the following concern, take $x \in \mathcal{A}$, then one has $$(I-P)(x_1,x_2,\dots) = (x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots) - (x_1, 0,0,\dots) = (0,x_2,x_3,\dots) \neq T T^{\ast} T (x_1,x_2,\dots)$$.      I believe you meant $T \circ T^{\ast} x = (0,x_2,x_3,\dots) = (I - P) (x_1,x_2,\dots)$. By your reference, one has $\sigma(T T^{\ast}) \neq \sigma(T T^{\ast})$. Can we deduct anything more from this claim?

Comment: Yes, there was one $T$ too many. What do you mean by "more"?

Comment: Does the non-commutativity of spectrum regarding adjoint operator, tell us that the underlying Banach Algebra is not for example $C^{\ast}$? (Is commutativity of spectrum regarding the adjoint operator a necassary condition for a special type of Banach Algebra i.e. Unital/Commutative/C^{\ast}?)

Comment: No. Your $\mathcal A$ is a C$^*$-algebra. And this only makes sense in a C$^*$-algebra where you have adjoints. In a Banach algebra, $T^*T$ makes no sense. Of course the fact that $T^*T$ and $TT^*$ can only happen in a non-commutative algebra, but a non-commutative algebra will also have elements where $T^*T$ and $TT^*$ have the same spectrum (every invertible $T$, for instance).

Comment: Yes you are right. I forgot that we that since we have $l^2(\mathbb N)$ as a Hilbert space this is clearly a $C^{\ast}$-Algebra. The last example also clearify the latter, thanks a lot.